# Python application permission denied

Tags: python, linux, macos, root, file-permissions

My Python program uses the terminal(system) command to perform the task on the file and script. I am going to convert this Python program into Mac OS application and Linux application using pyinstaller. I am going to pass the application installer file to my friends. However, I have following questions.

If script or file doesn't have proper permission which my program is trying to access, will Python get an error?

Running some script or opening file will require the permission of root. So is there a possible option that will prompt the user for root(admin) password or run my application with root privilege?

Thanks

Comment: You didn't mention what "task" you were performing on the file.Are you creating files in the directory? Are you reading files? As long as the user running your script has permission to access  the file you're fine. You can also handle the error which will be like this: IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Comment: I am creating the XML file with my Python program and copying that XML to two different directories. Another part of the python program will get the date of the system(user's machine) and information of directories(using `date` and `ls -al` terminal command using os.system library) and will post those data to my web application.

Comment: Well you'll need write access to the directories you're writing. I think using **date** doesn't require special permissions but using **ls** may require read permissions on that specific folder.

Answer (score 2):

Try `chmod 777 filname.py`, this will give the file all rights for execution and editing. There are also other modes for `chmod` like 755, which will also work for your case.

Comment: I am talking about accessing files in user's machine. So I will not be able to run the chmod in some directories because that will ask for root's privilege.